# Multistage docker build with no-cache

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-registry, docker-multi-stage-build

I have a multistage Dockerfile which is like below. When one of the image referred in the Dockerfile got updated, how to make sure latest versions are pulled again/always pulled while building image based on this Dockerfile. Running docker build command with --no-cache is still referring older versions of image but not actually pulling latest from docker registry.

```
docker build --no-cache -t test_deploy -f Dockerfile
```

```
FROM myreg.abc.com/testing_node:latest AS INITIMG
....
....
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build

FROM myreg.abc.com/testing_nginx:latest

COPY --from=INITIMG /sourcecode/build/ /usr/share/nginx/html
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`--no-cache` tells docker not to re-use cached layers. It does not pull images if they are already existing locally.
You can either `docker pull myreg.abc.com/testing_node:latest` before building or, more conveniently, also add `--pull` when calling `docker build`.

See https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#options